# why True, True, True == (True, True, True) in python3 gives the o/p True, True, False?

Tags: python-3.x

Why does python3 produce this output I am totally confused

```
>>>True, True, True == (True, True, True)
True, True, False
```

I also checked that for

```
>>>True == (True, True)
False
```

and for

```
>>True == (True)
True
```

Comment: Because it's `True, True, (True == (…))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because this expression is evaluated as follows:

```
 True, True, (True == (True, True, True))
```

where `True == (True, True, True)` turns into `False`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> True, True, True == (True, True, True)
(True, True, False)
>>> (True, True, True) == (True, True, True)
True
>>> True, True, True == False
(True, True, False)
>>>
```

You never actually compare the first two values because you're comparing 3 separate Trues against a tuple of booleans and only the last `True` that has `==` next to it is evaluated against a tuple type of multiple booleans. Since `True` is not equal to a different type. It effectively gets evaluated as `True == (True, True, True)` and prints the first two True statements along with it.

Types:

```
>>> type(True)
<class 'bool'>
>>> type((True, True, True))
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

So when you do that original check you're really doing the following check on the last True:

```
>>> type(True) == type((True, True, True))
False
>>> bool == tuple
False
>>>
```

Which since those types are not the same and the tuple is not truthy or falsey it resolves to False.